# Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] Angular js code does not working properly

Tags: angularjs

I am very new in angularJs. I am following a book to learn. There was an example here which is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

<head>
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>

function MyFirstCtrl($scope) {

var employees = ['Catherine Grant', 'Monica Grant',
'Christopher Grant', 'Jennifer Grant'
];

$scope.ourEmployees = employees;
}

</script>
</head>
<body ng-controller='MyFirstCtrl'>

<h2>Number of Employees: {{ ourEmployees.length}}</h2>
<p ng-repeat="employee in ourEmployees">{{employee}}</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Error is showing like this in console

> Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$controller/ctrlreg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error it seems you are using angular version 1.6. Then controller should not be global. It should be like follow,

```
var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){

});
```

**DEMO**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='testApp'>

<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);
app.controller('MyFirstCtrl',function($scope){
var employees = ['Catherine Grant', 'Monica Grant',
'Christopher Grant', 'Jennifer Grant'
];

$scope.ourEmployees = employees;
});
 

</script>
</head>
<body ng-controller='MyFirstCtrl'>

<h2>Number of Employees: {{ ourEmployees.length}}</h2>
<p ng-repeat="employee in ourEmployees">{{employee}}</p>

</body>
</html>
```